# #pragma warning clang/msvc compatibility

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, pragma

I'm writing some clang/msvc cross-compatible code.

It has come to my attention that clang does not treat this as an unknown warning:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4444)
```

(where 4444 is just an example; the actual disabled warnings are manyfold)

Is clang's (clang-c2 and llvm) interpretation of that `#pragma` disabling a warning at all similar to what cl.exe interprets the warning to be disabled?

Or are the numbers unrelated?

Comment: generates a warning if you specify -Wall: https://godbolt.org/g/y9jRSe
Which becomes an error with `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: Isn't the entire point of `#pragma` that the compiler can interpret it however it likes?

Comment: @Richard `-fms-extensions` or `-fms-compatibility` make that warning go away.  So that is evidence it is going to be compatible, if not strong evidence that the warning numbers remain meaningful.

Comment: @lcs I'm not asking about the C++ standard, but about a specific compiler (family), clang.  I'm asking how clang actually interprets it.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but too long to put as a comment.

The only mention I could find about implemented #pragma compatibility is here:

http://releases.llvm.org/3.6.2/tools/docs/UsersManual.html

> clang supports the Microsoft #pragma pack feature for controlling record layout. GCC also contains support for this feature, however where MSVC and GCC are incompatible clang follows the MSVC definition.
>
> clang supports the Microsoft #pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib") feature for automatically linking against the specified library. Currently this feature only works with the Visual C++ linker.
>
> clang supports the Microsoft #pragma comment(linker, "/flag:foo") feature for adding linker flags to COFF object files. The user is responsible for ensuring that the linker understands the flags.

No mention of #pragma warning, so I would suspect that it's silently ignored unless there's more information somewhere.

No idea how to test it, as I don't understand what conditions would produce a 4444 warning.

Also on that page:

> #### Microsoft extensions
>
> clang has some experimental support for extensions from Microsoft Visual C++; to enable it, use the -fms-extensions command-line option. This is the default for Windows targets. **Note that the support is incomplete.** Some constructs such as dllexport on classes are ignored with a warning, and others such as Microsoft IDL annotations are silently ignored.
>
> clang has a -fms-compatibility flag that makes clang accept enough invalid C++ to be able to parse most Microsoft headers. For example, it allows unqualified lookup of dependent base class members, which is a common compatibility issue with clang. This flag is enabled by default for Windows targets.

Comment: `4444` was just an example, not the only warning I care about.

Comment: @Yakk understood. I checked the 3.8 docs but there's no improvement. I would suspect that the pragmas are silently ignored. For them to make sense, clang would have to encapsulate all Microsoft diagnostics. This strikes me as unlikely.